# Displaying Text values from sister divs with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the value of the next texts in the 'title_head' divs  below after I click on the 'right_arrow' class.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="col-md-8 title">
       <div class="title_head">SHIRT</div>
       <div class="title_head" style="display:none">COLLAR</div>
       <div class="title_head" style="display:none">BUTTON</div>
       <div class="title_head" style="display:none">SLEEVE</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 right_arrow"><img src="img/arrows-right.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

My jQuery code is below.

```
var current = $('.title_head:visible').text();
var first = $('.title_head').first().text();
var last = $('.title_head').last().text();

$('.right_arrow').click(function(){
    if(current == last){
        $('.right_arrow').css('opacity','0.3');
        $('.right_arrow').css('cursor','default');
    }else{
        $(current).css('display','none');
        var val = $('.title_head').nextAll('.title_head:first').text();
        var next_val = $('.title_head').text(val);
        alert(next_val);
    }
});
```

The problem I am having is that when I alert the value for the 'next_val' it returns an object Object array. I think it is getting all the values of the other divs as a whole e.g "COLLARBUTTONSLEEVE" and not the individual values such as "COLLAR", "BUTTON", "SLEEVE".

I also need to display the next elements text as visible and hide the previously visible text sort of like an image slider but with text.

I hope this is clear. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: This line `var next_val = $('.title_head').text(val);` is returning a jQuery object. If you want to get the text you can do this `next_val.text()` If you look in the black header of http://api.jquery.com/text/ you see the return type of a function call. I have not checked the code but if it is an array you could get the value by using `next_val[0]` or any other index.

Comment: To me it not really clear what you want to achieve: If the user clicks on the right_arrow class the the value of a) the first title_head = SHIRT or b) the second title_head = collar should be returned? Is it a) or b)?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree thanks for the input. Rayan Bouajram had a perfect answer to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite your javascript to something more like this:

```
var items = $('.title_head'),
    index = 1; //start at position

$('.right_arrow').click(function(){

    if(items.length > index) {
        $('.title_head').hide();

        var $nextEl = $($('.title_head')[index++]),
            val = $nextEl.html();

        $nextEl.show();
        alert(val);
    }
    if(items.length === index) {
        $('.right_arrow').css('opacity','0.3');
        $('.right_arrow').css('cursor','default');
    }
});
```

**See the fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/rK4KR/1/

When you're querying for `.title_head` it will return back an array of nodes.  We can simply go through each position of that array and parse the value.  That way we don't have to always check to see which node is visible.

Comment: @user875139 anytime :).  Glad I could help!

Comment: @Ryan Bouajram what about if I added a left arrow in the mix to go backwards as well. Can you show me how to incorporate that into your solution? I tried a few things myself but it isn't work. What I tried was putting  var $prevEl = $($('.title_head')[index--]),
             val = $prevEl.html(); but that didn't work. Thanks

Comment: @user875139 Check out my fiddle here: jsfiddle.net/rK4KR/3/. You'll probably need to add a state logic for the buttons as the index is traveling on the array. Since the logic is determined by two buttons (not one) we will separate it out as its own function and process the view. I've made few minor tweaks to my original code to make this work.  Enjoy!

Comment: I hope to one day get on your level. Seriously thank you. Sometimes its hard for me to come up with logical solutions like that. I didn't even think about doing it that way. Guess more practice will do it. Are there any books or sites you can recommend to get better at things like this? Thanks again @Rayan Bouajram!

Comment: @user875139 Haha no worries. With good practice and patience you'll certainly get the hang of it and JS will become much easier for you. I'm sure there are many great books out there... I've stumbled onto this resource in the past: http://superherojs.com/.  I do suggest researching modular javascript patterns (and perhaps reading Gang of Four if you want to become a better programmer - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns).  Also try contributing to open source -- you'll learn a lot from that :). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Rayan Bouajram I will take a look at all those sources. Have a good one Buddy!